# Start programs without needing an extra terminal and from the desktop

Tags: shortcuts

I am a total newbie to Ubuntu and just installed it yesterday, so please explain it, so someone who almost never used Linux can understand.

I would like to not have to open a separate Terminal to open stuff like Teamspeak and FileZilla and have to keep it open.

To open FileZilla I just have to run `filezilla` in Terminal. For Teamspeak I have to navigate into that folder and run `./ts3client_runscript.sh` and then have to keep it open. How can I make desktop shortcuts for each the single command with Filezilla and the SH file for Teamspeak and make it, so I won't have a thousand terminals open the whole time?

And before anyone asks: I have the default desktop environment of the current Ubuntu LTS version. No idea how it's called. Would be great to know. Google just tells me three different ones.

Comment: You didn't tell us your release of Ubuntu, so we cannot know your desktop (if you are running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS then it's Unity, if running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS then it's Gnome; both are currently supported - latest LTS is 18.04 LTS so gnome?).   You can run commands in the background by appending a & at the end; so you don't need to have hundreds of terminals open.  eg. `filezilla &`

Comment: I tried running `filezilla &` but that doesnt change anything @guiverc

Comment: You should get your prompt returned (messages the program throws out will go to your terminal which can 'hide' your prompt (in that it'll scroll up your screen), but if you type a command like `ls` you'll list your files as you should (and your prompt will return).  To keep your terminals clean, I'd probably use one tab to background-run programs, and in that terminal (new tab) use it for your interactive use so that program messages don't mess up your display output.

Comment: @danzel does that work?  I'm using 19.10 and my system didn't have `gnome-desktop-item-edit` installed, though i have `gnome-tweaks` as the link says and all of `ubuntu-desktop` installed.  (why i didn't duplicate to that link; though could just be cause I'm on 19.10)

Comment: @guiverc, probably not. But there are numerous answers explaining how to create a `.desktop` file. That would be an interesting question for meta: should this not be closed as duplicate because the (by far) most upvoted answer is obsolete, even if the other answers are still valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create desktop shortcut for often used programs, no need to open terminal. Create shortcut by this commands:

```
cd ~/Desktop
nano filezilla.desktop
```

And put this into editor

```
[Desktop Entry]
Terminal=false
Name=filezilla
Exec=filezilla
Type=Application
```

For Teamspeek use following `Exec=` line in desktop shortcut:

```
Exec=bash -c 'cd /folderofteamspeek && ./ts3client_runscript.sh'
```

Comment: I only tried FileZilla yet, but when I double-clicked the FileZilla.desktop File, it says that it can't open untrustful applications and that the application starter is not marked as trustful. (I can't give you the exact message, as my Ubuntu is in German) It only allows me to Cancel

Comment: Try to make desktop file executable. `chmod u+x FileZilla.desktop`

Answer (score 0):

You can append an ampersand after the command like `filezilla &` which will open the app in background and can keep using the terminal but you won't get to see verbose output of the program on terminal.

Otherwise open the program normally and press **ctrl**-**z** to suspend the program and run `bg` to run it in the background and keep using the terminal.

*You can launch GUI softwares like filezilla by double clicking on the app icon without needing to launch it from terminal.*

Answer (score 0):

I think these distributions work with application maps, who are situated in /usr/share/applicatios and in /home/(user login name)/.local/share/applications where you have to put formentioned .desktop files.
In your file browser you can't see the /home/(user login name)/.local/share/applications map if you don't have the option "show hidden files' activated... but thats a file-manager preferences/options story :)